# c# how to get asp.net textbox value inside static web method?

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net

I want to call c# methods from JavaScript timer like below.

```
<script type="text/javascript">

     window.setInterval(DeleteKartItems, 10000);

     function DeleteKartItems() {
            PageMethods.DeleteItem();
            alert("test");
     }
</script>
```

**c# methods**

```
public static void DeleteItem()
{

     string query = "[Get_Messages]";
     SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query);
     cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
     cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@roomId", 5);
     GetData(cmd);
}

private static void GetData(SqlCommand cmd)
{
     string strConnString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["LinqChatConnectionString"].ConnectionString;
     using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(strConnString))
     {
          using (SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter())
          {
              cmd.Connection = con;
              sda.SelectCommand = cmd;
              using (DataSet ds = new DataSet())
              {
                  sda.Fill(ds, "Messages");
              }
          }
     }
}
```

So how to get `Label`/`TextBox` value inside above methods?

**I tried like below but its getting null value..**

```
Page page = HttpContext.Current.Handler as Page;
Label lblRoomId = (Label)page.FindControl("lblRoomId");
string lbRoomId = lblRoomId.Text;
```

ANY SUGGESTION ?

Answer (score 0):

Pass the label/textbox value in parameter.

```
PageMethods.DeleteItem(txtValue);
public static void DeleteItem(string txtValue)
{
// perform operation
}
```

Comment: First why are you using timer to call a method . I believe you want to delete after clicking on some delete button .

Check your methods syntax and try to debug the error you are getting

Comment: its just name , for test it first, i have to implement it for other purpose

Comment: i am using timer for get data from database for every one second and display it to on div..if i use asp.net timer control then div tag not working.

Comment: http://www.itorian.com/2012/07/calling-aspnet-c-method-web-method.html
check above example.

Comment: from this link only i got timer procedure but cant fire methode if i used parameters.